# pandas groupby ID then look for occurrence of 'H' character in the risk column of all rows

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have an example Pandas dataframe df:

```
ID    risk
1111  H
1111  H
1111  L
1111  L
1112  L
1112  L
1113  H
1113  L
1113  H
1113  H
1113  H
1114  L
1114  L
1114  L
1114  L
```

I want to group data based on ID and then look for occurrence of 'H' character in the risk column. If there exist any 'H' in the risk column in any of the rows of a specific ID, I would like to change all the rows of that specific ID in the risk column with 'H'. This is what I would like to get:

```
ID    risk
1111  H
1111  H
1111  H
1111  H
1112  L
1112  L
1113  H
1113  H
1113  H
1113  H
1113  H
1114  L
1114  L
1114  L
1114  L
```

I have a very big dataframe so how could I do that efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First find all unique `ID` by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and then replace values by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) or `loc` and [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
v = df.loc[df['risk'] == 'H', 'ID'].unique()
df['risk'] = np.where(df['ID'].isin(v), 'H', df['risk'])
```

Another solution:

```
df.loc[df['ID'].isin(df.loc[df['risk'] == 'H', 'ID'].unique()), 'risk'] = 'H'
```

And slowiest solution with `groupby`:

```
m = df.groupby('ID')['risk'].transform(lambda x: (x == 'H').any())
#better groupby alternative
#m = df['risk'].eq('H').groupby(df['ID']).transform('any')
df['risk'] = np.where(m, 'H', df['risk'])
```

---

```
print (df)
      ID risk
0   1111    H
1   1111    H
2   1111    H
3   1111    H
4   1112    L
5   1112    L
6   1113    H
7   1113    H
8   1113    H
9   1113    H
10  1113    H
11  1114    L
12  1114    L
13  1114    L
14  1114    L
```

Comment: Thanks, This works perfect. I tried your second solution (one line) and it worked like a charm. Thanks